# Breaking Up Massive MySQL Update

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, bigdata

Right now I have something like this in my CodeIgniter model:

```
<?php 
$array = array(...over 29k IDs...);
$update = array();
foreach ($array as $line) {
   $update[] = array('id' => $line, 'spintax' => $this->SpinTax($string));
   ### $this->SpinTax parses the spintax from a string I have. It has to be generated for each row.
}
$this->db->update_batch('table', $update, 'id');
?>
```

The first 20k records get updated just fine, but I get a `504 Gateway Time-out` before it completes.

I have tried increasing the nginx server timeout to something ridiculous (like 10 minutes), and I still get the error.

What can I do to make this **not** timeout. I've read many answers and HOW-TOs to segment the update, but I continue to get the server timeout. A `PHP` or CodeIgniter solution would be excellent, and I need to deploy this code to multiple servers that might not be using `nginx` (similar error in Apache).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much have you segmented it?

Comment: I use `array_chunk` for every thousand values, and nothing changes `foreach`ing over the chunks.

Comment: Think you'll need to run them in different sections, page loads rather.  Chunking them and running them one after the other on the same page load will likely end in the same result.

Comment: Before you do anything.  Try running it in the command line and adding set_time_limit(0); to the top of the file.

Comment: How might you go about doing that? Would doing a `redirect` to my method that keeps the value somewhere

Comment: You're using codeigniter, right? http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html I'm not sure how you're getting your array, but if its from the DB, just set a limit and offset and run it in intervals.

Comment: @wes added the `set_time_limit(0)`. It ran for much longer, but still got the `504` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll likely need to run this through command line and `set_time_limit(0)`.  IF you're in codeigniter, check this out on how to run a command line through the user guide. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html

Now, before you do that, you mentioned you are using array chunk.  If you're getting all the values from the database, no need to use `array_chunk`.  Just set a get variable for instance. 
/your/url?offset=1000, when that finishes, do a redirect to the same thing, but with 2000 and so on until it finishes.

Not the nicest or cleanest, but will likely get it done.

Comment: So you're saying, for example, pull 1000 on top of whatever the offset is?

Comment: wherever you get this from ($array = array(...over 29k IDs...);), set the query (if from a database) to limit to 1000,  so if your and just subtract the offset by 1000, limit 1000, offset 0...next would be offset 1000, limit 1000, etc...

Comment: thanks so much. Between the `set_time_limit()` function and the CLI bit, I've **finally* gotten it to execute across all the rows.